# Enum Deserializer Jackson-databind

Tags: java, json, enums, swagger, jackson-databind

While deserializing enums is it possible to convert space to '_' in jackson-databind or can @JsonProperty annotation be added to enum generated from the contract? Either from the contract or using the open API code generator? Any other solutions are also welcome.

When trying to deserialize using Jackson got the error

> cannot deserialize value of type clientSideType from String "Payment
> Declined": not one of the values accepted for Enum class:
> [PAYMENT_DONE, PAYMENT_PENDING, PAYMENT_DECLINED]

Manually written server-side enum

```
public enum serverSideType {
    PAYMENT_DONE,
    PAYMENT_PENDING,
    @JsonProperty("Payment Declined")
    PAYMENT_DECLINED;
}
```

Enum generated from the contract on client-side

```
public enum clientSideType {
    PAYMENT_DONE,
    PAYMENT_PENDING,
    PAYMENT_DECLINED;
}
```

Comment: You can implement a custom `StdDeserializer<ClientSideType>` that will replace the spaces with underscores then get the `valueOf` your enum.   Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69989340/jackson-enum-deserialization-delegation/69992979#69992979

Comment: Another option is using `@JsonValue` and/or `@JsonCreator` described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums).

Comment: @AndrewS clientSideType enum is generated from an open API contract, how can I add annotations to classes generated from a contract?